# How NodeJs resolve continuous operations?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are Event Loop that accepts callbacks and executes them, when need. And If I understand this is one thread event loop, so there is one callback that it executes at a time. I write test

```
setInterval(() => { console.log('INTERVAL')}, 801);
setInterval(() => { while(true) {  }}, 800);
```

There is the first `setinterval()` that arrives at event loop firstly. Second `setinterval()` (with infinite cycle) arrives secondly. So one thread executes `while(true)`, and it cannot execute `console.log('INTERVAL')`.

Is it means, if I F.E. will write server on NodeJs, that on one endpoint execute continuous calculations, and if one client sends the request, other clients should wait, until the server has served these long calculations and then will serve other clients?

P.S. in c# TPL, we use Tasks, and CLR thread pull creates two threads, and both of `Console.WriteLine("Interval")` and 'while true' executes parallel.

Comment: each 801 milliseconds the console will display 'INTERVAL' example
https://jsfiddle.net/t016czrL/

Comment: @Muath but if setInterval with the infinite loop will be first in the event loop, so that alert will never display: https://jsfiddle.net/4vmcwrqg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, server hangs if one endpoint is performing complex computations and if other endpoint requests, it must wait. Node has only one event loop and limited number of worker threads

You should not block the event loop. you should not perform the complex computations in node js synchronously or asynchronously.

Please refer this for more  information:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while(true){}`

Use this instead:

```
setInterval(() => { console.log('INTERVAL1')}, 801);
// change 1000ms with time you need
setInterval(() => {  {setInterval(() => { console.log('INTERVAL2')}, 1000)  }}, 800);
```

Comment: It's not a question about what to use, it is a question about what occurs if one client on my Node Js server sends the request that will be processed too long. Will other clients wait until the server serve the first client? And why, then, node js called a super backend language?